# Como ler um dataset através de http no R?

Tags: r, http

Tenho acesso através de um link:

```
'http://**.**.**.**/matrix/pesquisa_2019-03-17.feather'
ou
a<-readRDS('http://**.**.**.**/matrix/pesquisa_2019-03-17.rds')
```

Mas não consigo acessá-los

```
a<-read_feather('http://**.**.**.**/matrix/pesquisa_2019-03-17.feather')
Error in normalizePath(path.expand(path), winslash, mustWork) : 
  path[1]="http://**.**.**.**/matrix/pesquisa_2019-03-17.feather": A sintaxe do nome do arquivo, do nome do diretório ou do rótulo do volume está incorreta

a<-readRDS('http://**.**.**.**/matrix/pesquisa_2019-03-17.rds')
Error in gzfile(file, "rb") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In gzfile(file, "rb") :
  cannot open compressed file 'http://**.**.**.**/matrix/pesquisa_2019-03-17.rds', probable reason 'Invalid argument'
```

Consegui fazer o download com `download.file()`, mas não quero ocupar espaço no HD com ele.
Também consegui fazer com `read.csv2()` com a ajuda de: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/modules/reading-in-data-from-an-external-file/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sugiro adicionar o url() ao readRDS(), tipo readRDS(url("...")).
Exemplo:

```
test <- readRDS( url("https://github.com/derek-corcoran-barrios/LastBat/raw/master/best2.My.Lu2.rds") )
str(test)
```

Nota 1: os packages necessários para o objecto .rds devem ser importados antes.

Nota 2: o url deve ser o correcto. No caso do exemplo que utilizei, o ficheiro pode ser encontrado em https://github.com/derek-corcoran-barrios/LastBat/blob/master/best2.My.Lu2.rds; mas para funcionar no readRDS, tem que se utilizar o url que origina o download no browser. Neste caso é o https://github.com/derek-corcoran-barrios/LastBat/raw/master/best2.My.Lu2.rds